# SyntaxError raised when using joblib with lxml on python 3.5

Tags: python-3.x, lxml, joblib

I am trying to parallelize the tasks of correcting texts on many documents with Python, so I naturally found "joblib". I want each task to be to correct a given document. Here is the structure of the code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    lexicon = build_compact_lexicon()

    from joblib import Parallel, delayed
    import multiprocessing

    num_cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    results = Parallel(n_jobs=num_cores)(delayed(find_errors)('GDL', i, 1, lexicon) for i in range(1798, 1820))
```

I am using the function find_errors summed up here :

```
def find_errors(newspaper, year, month, lexicon):
    # parse the input newspaper text data using etree parser from LXML
    # detect errors in the text
    return found_errors_type1, found_errors_type2, found_errors_type3
```

This does raise me a few errors

```
multiprocessing.pool.RemoteTraceback: 
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mbl/anaconda3/envs/OCR_Correction/lib/python3.5/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 130, in __call__
    return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mbl/anaconda3/envs/OCR_Correction/lib/python3.5/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 72, in __call__
    return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
  File "/home/mbl/anaconda3/envs/OCR_Correction/lib/python3.5/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 72, in <listcomp>
    return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
  File "hellowordParallel.py", line 85, in find_errors
    tree = etree.parse(xml_file_path)
  File "src/lxml/lxml.etree.pyx", line 3427, in lxml.etree.parse (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:79801)
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1805, in lxml.etree._parseDocument (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:116293)
TypeError: cannot parse from 'NoneType'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mbl/anaconda3/envs/OCR_Correction/lib/python3.5/tokenize.py", line 392, in find_cookie
    line_string = line.decode('utf-8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb0 in position 24: invalid start byte

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mbl/anaconda3/envs/OCR_Correction/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 119, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "/home/mbl/anaconda3/envs/OCR_Correction/lib/python3.5/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 139, in __call__
    tb_offset=1)
  File "/home/mbl/anaconda3/envs/OCR_Correction/lib/python3.5/site-packages/joblib/format_stack.py", line 373, in format_exc
    frames = format_records(records)
  File "/home/mbl/anaconda3/envs/OCR_Correction/lib/python3.5/site-packages/joblib/format_stack.py", line 274, in format_records
    for token in generate_tokens(linereader):
  File "/home/mbl/anaconda3/envs/OCR_Correction/lib/python3.5/tokenize.py", line 514, in _tokenize
    line = readline()
  File "/home/mbl/anaconda3/envs/OCR_Correction/lib/python3.5/site-packages/joblib/format_stack.py", line 265, in linereader
    line = getline(file, lnum[0])
  File "/home/mbl/anaconda3/envs/OCR_Correction/lib/python3.5/linecache.py", line 16, in getline
    lines = getlines(filename, module_globals)
  File "/home/mbl/anaconda3/envs/OCR_Correction/lib/python3.5/linecache.py", line 47, in getlines
    return updatecache(filename, module_globals)
  File "/home/mbl/anaconda3/envs/OCR_Correction/lib/python3.5/linecache.py", line 136, in updatecache
    with tokenize.open(fullname) as fp:
  File "/home/mbl/anaconda3/envs/OCR_Correction/lib/python3.5/tokenize.py", line 456, in open
    encoding, lines = detect_encoding(buffer.readline)
  File "/home/mbl/anaconda3/envs/OCR_Correction/lib/python3.5/tokenize.py", line 433, in detect_encoding
    encoding = find_cookie(first)
  File "/home/mbl/anaconda3/envs/OCR_Correction/lib/python3.5/tokenize.py", line 397, in find_cookie
    raise SyntaxError(msg)
  File "<string>", line None
SyntaxError: invalid or missing encoding declaration for '/home/mbl/anaconda3/envs/OCR_Correction/lib/python3.5/site-packages/lxml/etree.so'
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hellowordParallel.py", line 160, in <module>
    results = Parallel(n_jobs=num_cores)(delayed(find_errors)('GDL', i, 1, lexicon) for i in range(1798, 1820))
  File "/home/mbl/anaconda3/envs/OCR_Correction/lib/python3.5/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 810, in __call__
    self.retrieve()
  File "/home/mbl/anaconda3/envs/OCR_Correction/lib/python3.5/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 727, in retrieve
    self._output.extend(job.get())
  File "/home/mbl/anaconda3/envs/OCR_Correction/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 608, in get
    raise self._value
SyntaxError: invalid or missing encoding declaration for '/home/mbl/anaconda3/envs/OCR_Correction/lib/python3.5/site-packages/lxml/etree.so'
```

I don't understand if this is due do something related with configs or if my function doesn't fit in a parallel implementation... (I guess it should...)

Did it happen to some of you before?

Hope my question is clear and there is enough information for someone to give me some help!

Comment: there is something really fishy going on. `etree.so` is a shared C library, not a Python source code module, yet it is being imported as one.

Comment: Oh yes, that's true. Well I installed my packages _lxml_ and _joblib_ using either `conda install` or `pip install` so I don't know why it is interpreting in such way a C library

Comment: I am not familiar with Joblib, but I think it is b0rken with extension class like `etree` fragments?

Comment: Well that would be strange, **joblib** seems to be the reference when trying to make for loops parallel in Python ad **lxml** is a popular package too... and I couldn't find similar issues somewhere else. I might do something wrong